# Young tableau (SU(3)) computation check

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, representation-theory

Young diagram of shape (a,b) has $a$ boxes in the 1st row, $b$ boxes in the second row.

Objective: decompose the following direct product of irreps, and then determine their dimensions given su(3)

(3,1) $\otimes$ (2,1)

I've determined this to be

(5,2) $\oplus$ (3,1) $\oplus$ (4,3) $\oplus$ (2,2) $\oplus$ (1) $\oplus$ (4) $\oplus$ (3,1)

I want to check that my dimensions are right (I'm having trouble with the inequivalence of irreps and their complex conjugates). I have

$15 \otimes 8 = 42 \oplus 24^* \oplus 15_a \oplus 15_b + 15_c \oplus 6^* \oplus 3$

where the labels on the 15's denote inequivalent irreps and the *'s represent complex conjugates

Comment: Looks plausible.  You don't know how to fit reps and their conjugates to a full 3 colun shape?

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand what you mean.

Comment: An  irrep and its conjugate, turned upside down, fit together into a rectangle of height 3 for SU(3), no?

Comment: yes precisely, that is how one finds the complex conjugate

Comment: why would I delete the question? I've still no answer as to whether the decomposition I've performed is correct

Comment: 1) are the dimensions of each diagram correct, 2) are the complex conjugates correct, 3) are the inequivalent irreps correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the whiff of doing your homework for you, and your having scrambled the *order* of the irreps so as to correspond their dimensionalities properly, yes, the answers are:

(2,1) ⊗ (3,1) = (5,2)  ⊕  (3,1)  ⊕  (4,3)  ⊕  (2,2)  ⊕  (1)  ⊕  (4)  ⊕  (3,1),

and, crucially, *in their proper order, not* your question's scrambled order, 
their dimensionalities unambiguously resulting from the [hook rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) and checkable by the arithmetic conservation of states (!) are

8 ⊗ 15 = 42  ⊕15 ⊕ 24$^*$⊕ 6$^*$⊕3 ⊕15 ⊕15 .

So, the only nontrivial equation is the first, resulting from [distributing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_series_from_the_tableaux) the 3 boxes, a,a,b, of the (2,1) onto (3,1). This *can only result in tableaux with 7,7-3=4, and 7-3-3=1 boxes, as you only chuck out 3-box towers--singlets.

This, then answers your question, about the conjugate reps: you cannot have a 6, so (2) with 2 boxes, or a 24, so (4,1) with 5 boxes. Moreover, note two of your 15s are of the original (3,1) type and the third one, the penultimate in this array, is a (4), instead.  Analogously, you can never have a 15$^*$, so (3,2), as this has 5 boxes, an unachievable number in the Kronecker multiplication involved.

One might well wonder how you'd have lingering doubts and of what type they could be.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware there was a proper order for the decomposition. Hmmm, so my analysis of the three inequivalent 15 irreps in incorrect.

Comment: There is no proper order, but the dimensionalities must be arranged in the same order as the Young tableaux they describe. You may devise your own order: 3 families for the first a, subfamilies thereof for the second, then the b....